# Change ExpandableListView edit view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How can I remove this in `ExpandableListview`?

[image]

Comment: Remove from your own layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove programmatically like this;

```
 getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);
```

By using  xml;

```
android:groupIndicator="@null"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:groupIndicator="@null"
```

use this property in your xml

Answer (score 1):

try this progrmattically

```
ExpandableListView yourListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.yourListView );

yourListView .setGroupIndicator(null);  

yourListView .setChildIndicator(null);
```

and tried changing `ExpandableListView's` attribute `android:groupIndicator="@null"`